# How do I create disabled scrollbar in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, scrollbar, tablelayoutpanel

I have a tablelayout panel with multiple columns. I have added another 2 tablelayout panels for header and footer since I don't want the vertical scrolling to affect the header and footer. However since there are 3 different tablelayout panels, I am unable to align the cell borders when we get vertical scrollbar in the center panel. One way looks to be to have a disabled scrollbar always present which gets enabled only when required. Checked but didn't find any references to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible :(... Did TrialAndError mechanism of aligning the components.